# cron job occasionally not running

Tags: linux, centos, cron, centos6

I have a `CentOS 6.6` server with the following packages installed:

```
crontabs-1.10-33.el6.noarch
cronie-1.4.4-12.el6.x86_64
cronie-anacron-1.4.4-12.el6.x86_64
kernel-2.6.32-504.3.3.el6.x86_64
```

Sometimes, one of the backup jobs that is scheduled to run daily simply does not run. The script is not even called according to `/var/log/cron.log`.
Interesting to mention that other jobs scheduled to run exactly at the same time run without any issues.

I can't reproduce the problem and haven't spotted any patterns on it. If I do nothing, then the job runs correctly the next day as expected.

crond simply ignores just one of the multiple jobs that are supposed to run at a particular time. This only happens sporadically.

I read in a few other places people talking about adding an empty line at the end of the `crontab` file. The job that's occasionally failing to run is indeed at the last line of my `crontab` file.
I could not find any confirmation this is a real or known bug.

```
# tail -2 /var/spool/cron/postgres
*  * * * * OTHERJOB
0 21 * * * /pg_backup.sh
```

This is all I have in my `/var/log/cron.log`

```
Mar 31 21:00:02 SERVERNAME [cron.info] CROND[19394]: (root) CMD (OTHERJOB)
Mar 31 21:00:02 SERVERNAME [cron.info] CROND[19418]: (postgres) CMD (/pg_backup.sh)
Mar 31 21:01:02 SERVERNAME [cron.info] CROND[20062]: (root) CMD (OTHERJOB)

Apr  1 21:00:02 SERVERNAME [cron.info] CROND[31349]: (root) CMD (OTHERJOB)
Apr  1 21:01:01 SERVERNAME [cron.info] CROND[32080]: (root) CMD (OTHERJOB)
```

See how `OTHERJOB` always run while on `Apr 1` `pg_backup.sh` was not even executed.

I've already tried restarting `crond` but this keeps happening. This is affecting multiple servers with the same version of OS, kernel and `cron` RPMs.

There is a newer version of `cronie` (`1.4.12`), however upgrading it is not an option as we're already using the latest available version for `Centos 6.6`

I went through the changelog for all `cronie` versions after mine (`1.4.4`) and haven't seem any fix to this particular problem. Also checked [all commit messages](https://git.fedorahosted.org/git/cronie.git).

Comment: Good troubleshooting. Why not try adding a noop last line (`echo >/dev/null` for e.g.)?

Comment: Is there any of your commands throw error. it could possibly stop the script. I had similar experience with init.d scripts.

Comment: How quickly does each of the jobs complete? If the job which you start every minute runs for two minutes each time, then that might be a problem. But if it completes in two seconds, then that probably isn't an issue.

Comment: The job that runs every minute (OTHERJOB) completes in a few seconds. But that's not the issue. I've only added OTHERJOB to the logs above to show that crond was running and OTHERJOB was processed correctly while pg_backup.sh simply didn't run.

Comment: Check `/var/log/audit/audit.log`.

Comment: What if you move that particular line to another location in your crontab file? Does some other cron job then start failing? The fact that the cronjob sometimes works makes this more difficult to solve. Have you ever tried to run `strace` against the cron process around 21:00 and see what it does?

Comment: Have *exactly* the same issue with exactly the same packages. It's extremely frustrating and disrupts our automation every other day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we use `sssd` for remote authentication. `crond` has to check for available users ahead of running jobs and it does this every 60 seconds.
`sssd` default `client_idle_timeout` is 60 seconds. so we had a race condition between `sssd` and `crond`

We only got to the bottom of this problem because on version `1.4.4-14` crond started being a bit more verbose about some errors.

```
* Thu Feb  5 12:00:00 2015 Tomáš Mráz <tmraz@redhat.com> - 1.4.4-14
- add log message when getpwnam fails
```

After updating to that version we started seeing the error below at the same time a job would not run:

```
[cron.err] crond[8654]: (user) ERROR (getpwnam() failed): Broken pipe
```

that brought us to this:
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1209600#c2

and finally to this:
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1125133

> Issue: `sssd_be` terminated with SIGKILL due to getpwnam() returning EPIPE
>   (ie. broken pipe) can cause crond to silently skip cron job entries.

The suggest solution on the link above was add the line below to `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`:

```
client_idle_timeout = 75
```

The change above has fixed the problem for us and cron no longer skips jobs.

Answer (score 7):

The original cron required each entry to end with a newline so yes sometimes you do need a blank line or something at the end.

```
   Although cron requires that each entry in a crontab end  in  a  newline
   character,  neither the crontab command nor the cron daemon will detect
   this error. Instead, the crontab will appear to load normally. However,
   the  command  will  never  run.  The best choice is to ensure that your
   crontab has a blank line at the end.

   4th Berkeley Distribution      29 December 1993               CRONTAB(1)
```

Some versions have it fixed or emit a warning for example Ubuntu Maverik (10.10) : [crontab](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/maverick/man5/crontab.5.html#contenttoc7) look at the diagnostics section at the bottom which states a warning will be written to syslog.

```
DIAGNOSTICS
       cron requires that each entry in a crontab end in a newline  character.
       If  the last entry in a crontab is missing a newline (ie, terminated by
       EOF), cron will consider the crontab (at  least  partially)  broken.  A
       warning will be written to syslog.
```

Answer (score 2):

This is the first answer that comes up with the search text `cron error getpwname failed` so I thought I would post the cause of my issue:

I was using /etc/crontab but had forgotten to put the user in front of the command.

i.e.,

```
*/5   *  *  *  * /bin/bash <filename>
```

Instead of

```
 */5   *  *  *  * root /bin/bash <filename>
```

It gave the same error, go figure.